# Empty String Boolean Logic

Tags: python, string, boolean

I just stumbled across this and I couldn't find a sufficient answer:

```
x = ""
```

Why then is:

```
x == True
False

x == False
False

x != True
True

x != False
True
```

Am I supposed to conclude that `x` is neither `True` nor `False`?

Comment: What?! You are to conclude that `x` isn't *equal to* either `True` or `False`. Why did you think it would be? Have you been confused somehow by https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing? It will still evaluate false-y in a boolean context: `if x:`, `bool(x)`, etc..

Comment: Dr. Tautology, I think what you meant to test was if `bool(x) == False`. Username checks out, though.

Comment: Now see what happens with your tests if you set `x=0`. And then do the same thing with `x=1`.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ask one bad question on stackoverflow and it ruins your day.FML

Comment: Hey, it's not _that_ bad. Sure, it's got a net zero score, but you won a few rep points from it, and you got some good answers. But yes, this is fairly basic info that isn't that hard to find in the official documentation.

Answer (score 6):

to check if x is True of False:

```
bool("")
> False

bool("x")
> True
```

for details on the semantics of `is` and `==` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

> Am I supposed to conclude that x is neither True nor False?

That's right. `x` is neither `True` nor `False`, it is `""`. The differences start with the type:

```
>>> print(type(""), type("x"), type(True), type(False))
builtins.str, builtins.str, builtins.bool, builtins.bool
```

Python is a highly object oriented language. Hence, strings are objects. The nice thing with python is that they can have a boolean **representation** for `if x: print("yes")`, e. g.. For strings this representation is `len(x)!=0`.

Answer (score 2):

In python '==' tests for equality.  The empty string is not equal to True, so the result of your comparison is False.

You can determine the 'truthiness' of the empty string by passing it to the bool function:

```
>>> x = ''
>>> bool(x)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Boolean context, null / empty strings are false (Falsy). If you use

```
testString = ""

if not testString:
    print("NULL String")
else:
    print(testString)
```

As snakecharmerb said, if you pass the string to the bool() function it will return True or False based

```
>>> testString = ""
>>> bool(testString)
    False

>>> testString = "Not an empty string"
>>> bool(testString)
    True
```

See this doc on Truth Value Testing to learn more about this:

Python 2:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Python 3:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing